# Is there a C# function that formats a 64bit "Unsigned" value to its equivalent binary value?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, string-formatting

To format/display a number to its equivalent binary form (in C#), I have always simply called:

```
Convert.ToString(myNumber, 2);
```

Today, I just realized that the .ToString() overload that I have been calling does not support values that are greater than 9223372036854775807. Note the .ToString() overload's signature is: `.ToString(long, int)`. Where "long" is a 64bit **signed** value which max's out at 9223372036854775807.

To put it another way, using C#, when I run this:

```
Convert.ToString(9223372036854775808,2);
```

It's no surprise (due to the signature) that I receive this exception message:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToString(object,
>   System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments
>     - Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

My question: Is there a .NET function that allows us to convert values greater than 9223372036854775807 to their equivalent binary format?

Comment: What exact format do you mean? Big-endian base-2?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can call it unsigned or signed, but its the same if you look at it bitwise!

So if you do this:

```
Convert.ToString((long)myNumber,2);
```

you would get the same bits as you would if there were ulong implementation of Convert.ToString(), and thats why there is none... ;)

Therefore, `((long)-1)` and `((ulong)-1)` looks the same in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no direct .NET equivalent like Convert.ToString(ulong, int).  You'll have to make your own, like the following:

```
public static string ConvertToBinary(ulong value){
  if(value==0)return "0";
  System.Text.StringBuilder b=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  while(value!=0){
    b.Insert(0,((value&1)==1) ? '1' : '0');
    value>>=1;
  }
  return b.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string UInt64ToBinary(UInt64 input)
{
    UInt32 low = (UInt32) (input & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    UInt32 high = (UInt32) (input & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
    return $"{Convert.ToString(high, 2).PadLeft(32, '0')}{Convert.ToString(low, 2).PadLeft(32, '0')}";
}
```